# rsyslog: execute script on matching log event

Tags: rsyslog

I have the following line in my `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
:programname, contains, "suhosin" /var/log/suhosin.log
```

which logs all php security related incidents to `/var/log/suhosin.log`. That is nice, but I would like rsyslog to execute my script `action.sh` instead of logging to file. How could I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for omprog.

```
module(load="omprog")
action(type="omprog"
       binary="/pathto/omprog.py --parm1=\"value 1\" --parm2=\"value2\"
       template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

See the docs for more details:
http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html

Answer (score 6):

The following runs "hi.bash" for me if a message contains "hellothere"

```
:msg, regex, "hellothere" ^/usr/local/bin/hi.bash
```

According to the docs, it waits for it to finish, so although it works, I imagine it causes dropped events.

There's a way to send a Templated parameter, but I haven't played with it.

Comment: Worked great! Make sure `hi.bash` has appropriate execute rights for your situation (ie 755).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use something like http://www.logcheck.org/ instead of running your script for each security incident via `rsyslog`.

Answer (score 1):

Suhosin can execute a script for each log message. Example php.ini:

```
suhosin.log.script=255
suhosin.log.script.name=/usr/local/bin/action.sh
```

From the documentation: "The script is called with 2 parameters. The first one is the alert class in string notation and the second parameter is the log message."